# HTA Loading XML

Tags: xml, hta

I have been tasked with loading an xml document and allow users to modify content of the xml and save when user is done. After saving I need to email that xml file admin to post on web site. I know that I can load, modify, and save xml documents using a server side code, but I have been tasked to find a way to do this using only javascript. This is an intranet application that only certain users will be able use, so I have decided to use an html application. 
I first started using VS to create a website to do this but then found out about not being able to save the xml document with javascript so I switched to an hta application. 
In VS I was able to load the xml document and display results inside a keno grid, but unable to save the xml. In my html application I can save an xml document but it will not load the xml with all of its nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<rpp>
  <city name="SomeName">
    <property>Owner</property>
    <location>Address</location>
    <phone>phone</phone>
  </city>
</rpp>
```

Javascript:

```
var xml = loadXMLDoc("rpp.xml");
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
    if (xhttp.overrideMimeType)
        xhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
    xhttp.send("");
    var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
    if (!xmlDoc) {
        if (isIE) {
            xmlDoc = getMSXmlParser();
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.loadXML(xhttp.responseText);
        }
        else
            xmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xhttp.responseText, 'text/xml');
    }
    return xmlDoc;
}
//code came from this site
//http://blog-rat.blogspot.com/2010/11/xmlhttprequestresponsexml-returns-null.html
function getMSXmlParser() {
    var parser = ['Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0',
                  'Msxml2.DOMDocument.5.0',
                  'Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0',
                  'Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0',
                  'MSXML2.DOMDocument',
                  'Microsoft.XMLDOM']; // the same as MSXML.DOMDocument
    for (var i in parser) {
        try {
            var xParser = new ActiveXObject(parser[i]);
            if (xParser) {
                return xParser;
            }
        }
        catch (e) { }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I load my xml with VS I retrieve all the nodes and their values and I am able to display that information in the kendo grid.
When I load my xml from hta there are no childNodes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using vbscript in your HTA. Here is a link to a great resource that has code for loading, saving, appending and editing xml using vbscript.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.02.heyscriptingguy.aspx?pr=PuzzleAnswer

Also, if you are new to HTML Applications then you can download the HTA Helpomatic from Microsoft. This is a demo HTA that contains specific HTA code.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17332